# WhatsApp videos are not viewable in iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone, video

I got a video in WhatsApp from someone with an Android phone. When I open the video I  can hear the the audio, but nothing is visible; it's just a blank screen with audio from the recording.

I forwarded the same video to my friend who has an  iPhone 7 and he is able to view (and hear) the video.

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix?  I am using an iPhone 6s.

Comment: Didn't you try to download and play it?

Comment: It's helpful to know what version of iOS and WhatsApp you are using and what version your friend is using.

Comment: i always hate to suggest this, but did you try restarting your iPhone? Also, if you have a computer, try using the WhatsApp Web/Desktop option and check if you can see the video on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the free VLC video app, it's available for iOS.